# Error in creating the kafka topic with replication factor 2 in a two broker cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

i have 2 broker kafka cluster, and i have configured the zookeeper of the two nodes into the both the borkers. Now when i try creating a topic with replication factor 2, it's showing that replication factor is larger than available brokers.

Node1 server.properties

```
broker.id=0
zookeeper.connect=10.142.0.4:2181,10.142.0.43:2181
log.dirs=/home/******/kafka-logs
```

Node 2 server.properties

```
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=10.142.0.43:2181,10.142.0.4:2181
log.dirs=/home/******/kafka-logs
```

when i tried two create a kafka topic with replication factor 2 and with partitions 2 its showing error.Below is my command to create a topic.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.142.0.43:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic logdata
```

Below is the errorr i am facing

```
Error while executing topic command : Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 0.
[2019-04-08 06:08:40,876] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 0.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Comment: Are you getting some error while starting Node-1 and Node-2 Kafka Server? Is Kafka server able to connect to Zookeeper client?

Comment: Are you able to create with replication factor of 1?

Comment: `available brokers: 0` doesn't look right. Have you checked your Kafka broker logs and confirmed that they're both running correctly?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati , I m able to start both the kafka servers. Bothe the brokers are running successfully

Comment: @VaibhavGupta yaa  I am able to create a topic with relication factor 1.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, Both the brokers are running successfully.